# Average over all positive functions on the unit interval whose Lebesgue integral is one

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, monte-carlo

I want to average over all positive functions on the unit interval whose Lebesgue integral is one. Formally, I want to compute the mean of the following probability distribution defined over function space $L^1[0,1]$
\begin{align}
P(f) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{c} &\text{ when }
\int_0^1 dx \; f(x) = 1\; ;
f(x) \geq 0\\
0 &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $c$ is a normalization factor.

Noticing the symmetry of the problem regarding variable $x$, we conclude that the result should be a constant. Then using the normalization, we find the mean 
\begin{equation}
\bar{f}(x) = 1
\end{equation}
I perform a Monte Carlo simulation on uniform grid in the interval $[0,1]$ and the result confirms the above conclusion...so far so good!

---

Now I do a variable transformation
$
z = x^2 \Rightarrow  \frac{dx}{dz} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{z}}
$. The probability distribution then becomes
\begin{align}
P(f) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{c} &\text{ when }
\int_0^1 dz \; \frac{f(\sqrt(z))}{2\sqrt{z}} = 1\; ;
f(z) \geq 0\\
0 &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Denoting $g(z)=\frac{f(\sqrt(z))}{2\sqrt{z}}$, we have the same initial probability distribution but with different names
\begin{align}
P(g) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{c} &\text{ when }
\int_0^1 dz \; g(z) = 1\; ;
f(z) \geq 0\\
0 &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
This distrbution is again defined over $L^1[0,1]$ (because whenever $g(z)$ is integrable, so is $f(x(z))$ and vice versa).

This means that I should get the same result as above but for the function $g(z)$ i.e.
\begin{align}
\bar{g}(z) = 1 &\Rightarrow  \frac{\bar{f}(\sqrt(z))}{2\sqrt{z}} = 1 \\ &\Rightarrow \bar{f}(x) = 2 x
\end{align}
which is different from the previous result $\bar{f}(x)=1$!

---

That was just one example. In general, when I do a variable transformation from $x$ to $z$, the result is
\begin{align}
\bar{f}(x) = \frac{dz}{dx} \text{ (up to a normalization factor)}
\end{align}
So the results depend on the variable that the problem is expressed in.
When I performed Monte Carlo simulations on different nonuniform girds (which correspond to different variable transformations) I did get different results and the results confirms the above relation.

---

It looks like that *"a uniform probability distribution over all positive functions on the unit interval whose Lebesgue integral is one"* is not mathematically well-defined because its mean depends on the way I compute it.

I understand that the source of these different results is the hidden assumption about the **symmetry** of all the points in the interval $[0,1]$. Since the points get compressed or stretched upon variable transformation, I get different results.

Is there a mathematically rigorous way of expressing this assumption and including it in the definition of the probability distribution?

Comment: There is no "normalization" which would make $P$ a probability distribution. There are infinitely many such $f$

Comment: You are right but the concept of a "random function" is not strange and  we see it in different areas like path integrals and stochastic process. So maybe I should ask the following:

What is the mathematically rigorous way of expressing probabilities over function spaces?

Comment: There is no **the** way, there are ways. You may want to start with [Wiener measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Wiener_space#Classical_Wiener_measure) on continuous functions.